# How to redirect to external site?

Tags: web, wampserver

I am using Netbeans J2EE. When put `href="www.google.com"` in a button in my web application I get `http://localhost:8084/www.google.com` in the address bar. Thus, I can't access to google. What should I do to get out of the localhost and redirect to any external web site?

Comment: Do you have some example code?

Comment: use `href="http://www.google.com"` to stop it being assumed to be a relative address on your server.